# raspberry pi 3 Ethernet with 802.1X

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to connect my raspberry pi 3 via Ethernet to the Interet. The problem is that in my student dorm they use 802.1X as network authentication. I found this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication and did the steps. 
So i modified /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. It looks like this now:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
eapol_version=2
ap_scan=0
network={
key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
eap=PEAP
identity="loginname"
password="password"
phase1="peaplabel=0"
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

But when i run:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wired -i eth0
```

The output is:

```
Succesfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCGIFFLAGS]: No such device
setsockopt: No such device
ioctl[SIOC{ADD/DEL}MULTI]: No such device
ioctl[SIOCGIFFLAGS]: No such device
wpa_driver_wired_init: Could not get interface flags
eth0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

And i dont have a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've absolute no knowledge about the protocol you ask about, but as far as I know the new raspbian, has changed the names of the network interface "eth0" to enp3s0 or so.

You can verify my assuption by performing `sudo ifconfig -a`.

Then you get a list off all your interfaces. If "eth0" is not in this list, there should be something like "enpXsY". In this case you just have to change the "eth0" in the command above to the new interface name. E.g.:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wired -i enp0s3
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much, everything works now :)